# How to query data between specific time, regardless of their date?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called *event* to record the whole month data, and it has one column called *EventTime* to record the time each of them been written into database.

Could I query the data in specific time range, regardless of their date?
For Instance, I want to query the data between 12:00 and 18:00, then it could return all data which occur between the time range in the whole month?

I believe I could do it with a for-loop in my C# code, but I'd like to know is there any SQL command I could use?

Comment: What is the datatype of your EventTime column?

Comment: It's type is "DataTime", the form of data stored in that column is something like '2015-12-14 18:00:00'

Answer (score 1):

You cast the column to TIME and query it.
example:

```
select time(event_time) from events where time(event_time) BETWEEN '10:00' and '11:00'
```

the downside of this approach is that the DB won't use any index on event_time (unless you created a function based index on time(event_time))

Comment: This provide the EventTime data of the events in specific range correctly, but what I exactly need are the events. Still appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Time Function here is complete detail of [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
-- it will pull all records within current Month i.e December Now and given Time Range.
    Select Time(EventTime) from event where MONTH(EventTime) = Month(Current_Date) and  time(EventTime) BETWEEN '12:00' and '18:00'
```